# Change background colour of selected listview items permanently untill another items get selected

Tags: android, background-color

I want to change background colour of selected item permanently until another item selected. I've tried many answered on stackoverflow but not get required solution. I'm using list Fragment. Code of this,

```
public class LeftFilterContents extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    Get get;
    View view;
    ListView listView;
    AdapterLeftFilterContents adapter;

    public interface Get {
        void getData(int s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            get = (Get) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        arrayList.add("Type");
        arrayList.add("Date");
        arrayList.add("From to Date");

        adapter = new AdapterLeftFilterContents(getActivity(), R.layout.single_list_item_view, arrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        get.getData(position);
    }
}
```

list_fragmnet.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#666666">
    </ListView>
```

single_list_item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_left_filter_contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is provide a selector to either the `TextView` or the parent `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_list_selector">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_left_filter_contents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new `Drawable Resouce File` in your app's `drawable` folder.

**my_list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
      <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/controlbar_gradient" />
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**control_bar_gradient.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient

        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#7e0809"
        android:endColor=  "#fa0000" />
</shape>
```

And finally simply *select* the clicked view and *unselect* the previous ones.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
    if (prevSelectedView != null
        prevSelectedView.setSelected(false);
    view.setSelected(true);
    prevSelectedView = view;

    get.getData(position);

    // Here provide position to the adapter to update views in case of scrolling
}
```

Comment: what will be the prevSelectedView?

Comment: @ZohaibSiddique prevSelectedView is a View defined in LeftFilterContents's scope.

Comment: Why don't you add some useful information like what doesn't work. Like You don't get a selection highlighter or the view doesn't retain the state, etc.

Comment: view doesn't retain the state

Comment: Again more information will be welcome. Regardless if the view doesn't retain state after scrolling then it might be because you paid no attention to my last comment. You need to provide your adapter with the selected position, so it can select the position when a view has scrolled out of bounds and back into.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create `List<Object>`  and store in which position user has clicked. after that just do `notifydatasetchanged();` method.
In get view method of adapter according to the saved position change the background color of selected row.